# what keypress() function apply in real life

Tags: javascript, jquery

I do the example moving next article using keypress() from codeacademy about interactive Websites and it' so hard to access in website, press key one time it working but 2nd time it doesn't work. So i was confused what keypress() do in real life

Answer (score 3):

You use the `keypress` *event* (not function) to respond to the user pressing keys on the keyboard that result in a character being generated, like the `x` key. You can use it for anything you like. Google uses it for keyboard shortcuts in GMail, for instance.

Here's an example: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/wofed/1/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Click anywhere on this document, then press keys.</p>
<script>
  (function() {
    "use strict";

    document.addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
      display("You pressed: " + String.fromCharCode(e.which || e.keyCode));
    }, false);

    function display(msg) {
      var p = document.createElement('p');
      p.innerHTML = String(msg);
      document.body.appendChild(p);
    }
  })();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```